# Php script not executed on Apache server

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have this login system. Forms shows up but direct straight to index.php when login pressed with wrong credentials. No error message... nothing. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Heres my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include_once("db.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);

    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $db_password = $row['password'];

    if($password == $db_password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "You didn't enter the correct details!";
    }

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family:         Tahoma;">Login</h1>
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
    <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Comment: Your form action is set to `index.php`. It should be set to `login.php` or whatever the name of your login script is

Answer (score 0):

Is this form your index.php page? The form action is index.php so it posts to the index page and never runs your code on POST. Remove `action="index.php"` from the form element so that it posts to the current script. I assume it's different since you are doing a 301 redirect on successful login.

A few recomendations would be to throw an `exit()` after the header function in the redirect. Also, you could set a variable for the form error and put it in with your markup. Here is an updated script:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    include_once("db.php");
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $username);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $password);

    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $db_password = $row['password'];

    if($password == $db_password) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $error = "You didn't enter the correct details!";
    }

}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-family: Tahoma;">Login</h1>
<?php if (!empty($error)) echo '<div class="login-error">' . $error . '</div>'; ?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input placeholder="Username" name="username" type="text" autofocus>
    <input placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password">
    <input name="login" type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

Hope that helps!

I would also recommend using the PDO driver over MySQLi. That can really help prevent SQL injection, especially if you're learning and planning on deploying to a production environment.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php